# wxWidgets failed to register window class on Windows when using wxMathPlot as DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, wxwidgets

I am writing a cross platform application in C++ that is creating some plots. For GUI I am using wxWidgets 3.1.3 and for plots wxMathPlot.

On linux it works great but on Windows I get the following error:

```
...\src\msw\window.cpp[3994]:assert "wclass" failed in wxWindow::MSWCreate(): failed to register window class?
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019. The error is present on both Debug and Release, but only when I am using wxMathPlot as DLL.

I've tried to recompile wxWidgets and to add propriety sheet from wxWidgets to wxMathPlot project but I get the same error.

It's not a requirement of the project to use wxMathPlot as DLL but I am curious on why this behavior happens.

[image]

Comment: By default window classes are registered privately per module, and only that module can create windows of that class. While you can register 'global' window classes (global here means global to the calling process) you can create windows from anywhere in the process, though you still have to pass in the correct module handle.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you use wxWidgets as a DLL as well, but you really need to do it in order for it to work, i.e. both the mathplot DLL and your main application must define `WXUSINGDLL` when compiling and link with the DLL import libraries. Otherwise you'd end up with 2 copies of the same static library in the same process, which can create many problems.

Comment: Multiple copies of the same static library can cause all sorts of wrong, though the error in the question is not one of those.